# WP_Query in functions.php overrides global $post object, even with wp_reset_query()

Tags: posts, functions, wp-reset-query

I've written a function that grabs all posts that are drafts and puts them as a dropdown in my toolbar for easy access to complete. This works just fine.

The problem is that it seems to mess with my global $post object, specifically when called in my post/page editor.

So if I'm in my post editor: http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=147&action=edit

147 is the post I want to edit. But instead of showing the post corresponding to 147, it's showing the last draft in the loop, even though I'm resetting the query variable with wp_reset_query().

Thanks!

Here's my function:

```
// Get Company Drafts
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'add_nodes_and_groups_to_toolbar', 1000 );
function add_nodes_and_groups_to_toolbar( $wp_admin_bar ) {

  $user_id = bp_loggedin_user_id();
  $draft_query = new WP_Query(array(
      'connected_type' => 'companies_to_users',
      'connected_items' => $user_id,
      'nopaging' => true,
      'post_status' => 'draft'
  ));

  if ($draft_query->have_posts()) {

    // Add 'Drafts' to the Toolbar
    $args = array(
        'id'    => 'drafts',
        'title' => 'Drafts',
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );

    // Add the category 'Companies' as the sub-menu of Drafts 
    $args = array(
        'id'     => 'drafts_company',
        'title'  => 'Companies',
        'parent' => 'drafts'
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );

    while($draft_query->have_posts()) : $draft_query->the_post();

        // Add the post title as the sub-menu of the category sub-menu
        $args = array(
            'id'     => $post->ID,
            'parent' => 'drafts_company',
            'title' =>  get_the_title(),
            'href'   => apply_filters('gform_update_post/edit_url', $post->ID, home_url('/edit-company/'))
        );

        $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );

    endwhile;
  }

  wp_reset_query();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `wp_reset_postdata` attempts to restore `$post` from the main `$wp_query`, but on `post.php` in admin, `$post` isn't populated from `$wp_query`, so `wp_reset_postdata` fails to restore it. The solution is to use `get_posts` and a `foreach` instead of `WP_Query` and the loop.